# How to get element of spark millib matrix using coordinate

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

For example, if I have a matrix:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrices}

// Create a dense matrix ((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0))
val dm: Matrix = Matrices.dense(3, 2, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0))

dm:
1.0  2.0
3.0  4.0
5.0  6.0
```

If I want to know get (1,2) of dm which is 2, what should I do.
I searched the internet, and could not find a proper API.

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is useful-

```scala
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrices => OldMatrices, Matrix => OldMatrix}

    // Create a dense matrix ((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0))
    val dm: OldMatrix = OldMatrices.dense(3, 2, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0))

    println(dm)
    /**
      * 1.0  2.0
      * 3.0  4.0
      * 5.0  6.0
      */
    // /** Gets the (i, j)-th element. */ index starts from 0
    println(dm.apply(0, 1))
    // 2.0
```